# Can we install Visual Studio 2017 side-by-side with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide, visual-studio-2017

Currently installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional.
Want to install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition side-by-side.

Will 2017 break 2010?

Microsoft website claims that 2017 can be installed side-by-side with 2015, 2013 and 2012.

On MSDN, [Visual Studio 2017 Platform Targeting and Compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-vs) article claims:

> You can install and use Visual Studio 2017 alongside previous versions
>   of Visual Studio, including Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013,
>   and Visual Studio 2012.

But, they do not mention 2010.

Comment: Not sure about 2017, but I have 2005, 2010 and 2013 on the same platform and I have no problems.

Comment: Finally, I took the plunge in 2018. They worked side-by-side without any issue. Your mileage may vary especially if you rely on some VS extensions in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In the section **"Visual Studio 2017 Support for Windows Development"** of the MSDN page you have linked there's a table.

In the row that starts with **"Windows Server 2003"** it is reported that:

> Remote debugging and profiling tools are not available. Managed
>   development requires using Visual Studio .NET multi-targeting and
>   **requires side-by-side installation of Visual Studio 2010**. For more information, see: A Look Ahead at the Visual Studio 2012 Product
>   Lineup and Platform Support.

so apparently side-by-side installation of Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2017 is supported.

Comment: I saw that. However, it does not explicitly state that they're fully compatible. We have a huge 2010 solution. I can't let 2017 break it even slightly. I wish they work without a glitch. Thanks for your input.